# Get all entries for a given name in firefox form history

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way I can find out all elements of a given name in teh form history. In my firefox addon, I am adding some elements in the form-history under a specific name - lest say "search-description".

I now want to get all the elements I added under this name. I see that I can get a history object :

```
this.Ci = Components.interfaces;
this.Cc = Components.classes;
var historyObj = this.Cc["@mozilla.org/satchel/form-history;1"].getService(this.Ci.nsIFormHistory2 || this.Ci.nsIFormHistory);
```

But the nsIFormHistory or nsIFormHistory2 interfaces do not have any function like:

```
getAllEntries(name)
```

Anyone can help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `nsIFormHistory2.DBConnection` property is used for querying, you access the SQLite table directly. Something like this (untested):

```js
var completionListener =
{
  handleCompletion: function(reason) {},
  handleError: function(error) {},
  handleResult: function(result)
  {
    var values = [];
    while (true)
    {
      var row = result.getNextRow();
      if (!row)
        break;
      values.push(row.getResultByName("value"));
    }
    alert("Autocomplete values: " + values);
  }
};
var query = "SELECT value " +
            "FROM moz_formhistory " +
            "WHERE fieldname='search-description'";
var statement = historyObj.DBConnection.createAsyncStatement(query);
historyObj.DBConnection.executeAsync([statement], 1, completionListener);
```

Note that using async API is recommended here, querying the database might take time.